# Understanding applets

Tags: java, applet, client-server, client

*I have to call .exe file on client.*

But I dont understand sevler-client communication using Applets.

**So few Q:**

1.Can I do my task using Applets?

2.Does applets jar methods called on server?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Applet does not maintain a state-full communication between client and server.

It is a Java application that runes inside the browser and has an access to a local system resources (if signed) and existing browser session, i.e. can use the same cookies to perform HTTP calls within the same Server-Side session.

1) Yes, you can do you task in Applet as in any other java application, however, in case of Applet it must be signed with the digital signature: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/java-code-signing-1915323.html#60

2) No. All the classpath dependencies Applet may have, will be downloaded and cached on the client machine. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/deploymentInDepth/index.html

Comment: Oh thanks. Can you tell me, how properly place applets jar into war file? (Or here's another way to make it?) Which path applet will be using? I'm making webapp, and need to call applet from servlet (is that good?) ?

Comment: Take a look at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/deploymentInDepth/index.html. It describes how the applet and the required jars must be deployed. It depends on what way of deploying will you select -JNLP or TAG. Regarding the servlet - not sure what you mean by calling applet from servlet? You call certain method of applet using javascript, which is generated/outputted by servlet, but you can not call applet which is client side application, from the servlet which is server side application.

Comment: Hey, Ive done with applet, add my lib(its not good way I know) into  resources and as result have it in the root of my jar. Also I've made self-signing to applet(so I have access to my system files). Now I get exception, that cant find my lib. Can you tell me, where I should place it?

Comment: What kind of lib is that? Can you post an exception?

Comment: See please http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21928936/applets-jar-cant-find-resource

Answer (score 0):

File system access is often not allowed as applets can (should) run in a sandbox limited-privileges environment. So running an exe file is possible only if the applet has proper permissions. Typically they are given such permissions when signed.

That being said, try not to use applets and write proper Java applications instead. You can always wrap the Java app in an applet, so that it is started from the applet.

Not so sure what you mean by the second question.