# Applets Jar cant find resource

Tags: java, jar, applet

I've made applet, Here's files from its jar.

[image]

In my classes I've call `ffmpeg.exe`, and I have all privileges like self-signed applet and make call via Access Controller. So I've getting error in program, It's can't be find `*my ffmpeg lib*`.

This should be very easy Q: where should I place my **ffmpeg.exe file** ?

And I've get exception as:

```
Cannot run program "ffmpeg": CreateProcess error=2, ?? ??? ??? ????? ????
```

The code are following as:

```
public class DtpVideoApplet extends Applet 
{
  public String startRecording() throws IOException 
  {
  try
  {
    return(String) AccessController.doPrivileged(new PrivilegedAction<String>()
    {
    public String run() 
    {
    try 
    {
    Runtime.getRuntime()
    .exec("ffmpeg -y -f dshow -i video=\"screen-capture-recorder\" output.flv");
    return "Entered";
    }
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    return e.getMessage();
    }
    }
    });
    } 
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
    return e.getMessage();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the code doing (post it), and what exception do you get (post the complete stack trace)?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I updated my Q. As you can see, I just return getMessage(I received this exception while locating of ffmpeg lib wasnt under classpath). Can you suggest me how to get all printstacktrace for this applet?

Comment: I'm executing cmd's cmd 'dir' and receive '.../Desktop', so just moving forward now

Comment: Yep, my *exe should be placed on a Desktop, but WHY ? How to change this?

Comment: Your exe should be placed in a directory that is listed in the PATH environment variable if you want to be able to execute ffmpeg. Or it should be placed in any directory, and your code should pass path of the exe to exec().

Comment: I understand, but how to do specify some location? (see my exec() please)

Comment: I understand, but how to do specify some location? (see my exec() please). I also read, that applet should be cached. Does applet downloaded only once? If yes, so I'd like to add ffmpeg to resources and run it from applets jar ? Is it good?

Comment: You'll have to extract the exe file from your jar and copy it on the hard drive somewhere (in a temp directory).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48043/discussion-between-user2171669-and-jb-nizet)

Answer (score 0):

I never run an .exe from an applet, however I'm load some .dlls from an applet resource, to do this first I copy my applet resources to temp path and then I load it from this path. The dlls are located inside the jar how is showed below:

[image]

loadLib method copies .dlls to disc and then load it, this method receive as parameters the directory and the name of the file (in my case the method call is loadLib("/sun/security/mscapi/","sunmscapi_x32.dll"); )

```
public static void loadLib(String libraryPath, String libraryName) throws    IOException, InterruptedException{

    System.out.println(libraryPath + "---------------------");
    URL inputStreamLibURL = AddSunMSCAPIProvider.class.getResource(libraryPath);
    if(inputStreamLibURL==null){
        throw new IOException("Resource not found: " + libraryPath);
    }

    String tempPath = System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir", NOT_FOUND);
    if(tempPath.equals(NOT_FOUND)){
        throw new IOException("Temporary File not found");
    }
    File tempDir = new File(tempPath);

    //first try to overwrite the default file
    File defaultFile = new File(tempPath, libraryName);

    boolean useDefaultFile = false;
    if(defaultFile.exists()){
        try{
            useDefaultFile = defaultFile.delete();
            //return false if the library cannot be deleted (locked)
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            useDefaultFile = false;
        }
    }else{
        useDefaultFile = true;
    }

    File tempFile;
    if(useDefaultFile){
        tempFile = defaultFile;
    }else{
        tempFile = File.createTempFile(libraryName, "", tempDir);
    }

    copy(inputStreamLibURL.openStream() ,tempFile, 0);

    Runtime.getRuntime().load(tempFile.getAbsolutePath());
}

/**
 * File copy
 * @param src
 * @param dest
 * @param bufferSize
 * @throws IOException
 */
private static void copy(InputStream src, File dest, int bufferSize) throws IOException{
    if(bufferSize<=0){
        bufferSize = 2000; //default bytebuffer
    }
    InputStream is = src;
    OutputStream os = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(dest));
    byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
    int c;
    while((c = is.read(buffer))!= -1){
        os.write(buffer, 0, c);
    }
    is.close();
    os.close();
    return;
}
```

Of course in order to do this operations, the applet must be correct signed and necessary MANIFEST permissions added.

Hope this helps,

Comment: Tnx you alot for your answer, can you answer MY last comment under my Q? Tnx in advance.